# Can't install sqlite3 on jruby - failed to install native extensions

Tags: windows, jdbc, sqlite, jruby

I am doing the One month rails tutorial over at www.onemonth.com and I have ran into this issue.

It appears that sqlite3 will not install properly because it disagrees with jruby. This man's blog post was very insightful and seemed like it would be the end to my woes: https://jrubyist.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/jruby-and-sqlite3-living-together/

Yet, I am still running into `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` So I am not sure where to go from here. It seems like I have exhausted the internets knowledge of problems concerning jruby, sqlite and windows together.

Maybe I didn't configure the database.yml file properly?

github:https://github.com/dripper91/trident

Comment: It would help to see the output lines before the "ERROR: ..." line.

Comment: ok here it is: ![error message](http://i.imgur.com/uifqIXv.jpg)